# Posts 2 Posts Plugin : error message everywhere

Tags: plugin-posts-to-posts

Just upgraded to the last version of Posts 2 Posts plugin (I have the last WP version too) and I have the following error message on every dashboard page :

« Warning: Connection types without a 'name' parameter are deprecated. in /home/.../wp-content/plugins/posts-to-posts/core/api.php on line 59 »

Plus my website layout is destroyed.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by adding a 'name' parameter to your `p2p_register_connection_type()` call, as shown in the wiki:

https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Basic-usage

Comment: Thanks scribu, that worked (and thanks a lot for maintaining your awesome plugin)